# Is the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content-type accepted for the Azure Functions httpTrigger?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

In my C# Azure Function I have a httpTrigger with this binding configuration:

```
{
  "authLevel": "anonymous",
  "name": "req",
  "type": "httpTrigger",
  "direction": "in",
  "methods": [
    "post"
  ]
},
```

Inside the method I can do a `req.Content.IsFormData()` and `True` is returned. When I do a `req.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync()`, nothing is returned. If I log the `req.ToString()`, the content has a zero length.

Where in the code (on Github.com) would be the best place to look for this answer? I could not find it. Thanks.

Here is the code, sorry for not posting it originally.

```
using System.Net;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log, ICollector<string> outputSbMsg)
{

    var formdata = await req.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync();

    if (formdata.Count == 0)
    {
        log.Info("No Keys");
    }

    string message = $"Service Bus queue message created at: {DateTime.Now}"; 
    log.Info(message); 
    outputSbMsg.Add(message);

    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

}
```

Comment: Would you like to post the code of your function also please ?

Comment: This should be supported, but it will just be the raw data. See this [issue on our GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/317) to track fixing this. Posting a code sample would help me repro this issue.

Comment: Hi @ChrisAnderson-MSFT I did see that issue and I thought it might be the same issue but wanted to make sure. Please let me know if I did anything "unusual" in the code above. Thanks. Go Azure Function!